# Django template default filter with nullable boolean values

Tags: django, django-1.8

I need to pass a boolean variable to a template. To convert it to js boolean you usually do:

```
{{ boolval|yesno:'true,false' }}
```

Now my `boolvar` may not exist. In that case I need it to default to `true`, so I am trying this:

```
{{ boolval|default_if_none:'true'|yesno:'true,false' }}
```

Unexpectedly, the result of this is `false`.

I am trying to debug what `{{ boolval|default_if_none:'true' }}` produces but I am getting syntax errors. Not sure what's going on, but it is definitely not producing `true`.

How can I achieve *with filters* the behavior I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More simple and straightforward solution, in my opinion, is `{{ boolval|lower }}`.

No additional overhead and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

[`default_is_none`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none) only use the given value if the value is `None`. If `boolval` is missing from the template context, then it will evaluate to the empty string by default, which is not the same as `None`.

If you can't ensure that `boolval` is present in the template context, then I suggest you write a [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) with `takes_context=True`. I don't believe it's possible to write a filter that can tell the difference between a missing variable and the empty string.